# Auto Layout with UITextField causes exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, autolayout

I'd like to position a **UITextField** inside a **UIViewController** view using auto layout (dynamic resizing and a 5 pt margin between the textfield and its superview). I create the view programmatically using the **loadView** method.

Header of UIViewController

`@property (weak, nonatomic) UITextField *textField;`

Implementation

```
-(void)loadView{

    //Frame
    UIView *frame = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40)];
    [self setView:frame];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    //TextField
    [self.textField setDelegate:self];
    [self.textField setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [frame addSubview:self.textField];

    [frame addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(5@50)-[textField(==10@10)]-(5@50)-|"
                                                                  options:0
                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                    views:@{@"textField" : self.textField}]];

    [frame addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: @"V:|-(5@50)-[textField(==10@10)]-(5@50)-|"
                                                                  options:0
                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                    views:@{@"textField" : self.textField}]];

//    //Test with UIView instead
//    UIView *sub = [[UIView alloc]init];
//    [sub setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
//    [sub setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
//    [frame addSubview:sub];
//    
//    [frame addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(5@50)-[sub(==10@10)]-(5@50)-|"
//                                                                  options:0
//                                                                  metrics:nil
//                                                                    views:@{@"sub" : sub}]];
//    
//    [frame addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: @"V:|-(5@50)-[sub(==10@10)]-(5@50)-|"
//                                                                  options:0
//                                                                  metrics:nil
//                                                                    views:@{@"sub" : sub}]];
```

Running this throws an exception. Curiously using a UIView ("sub") as subview instead (the part commented out) does work as expected.

Ouput:

[image: Auto Layout with UIView]

Shouldn't the textfield behave just like this UIView? How come the textField causes an exception?

---

New finding: The app crashes only when I use **addConstraints** on the **self.textField**. If I remove those two calls I spare the crash, however the textfield doesn't show up either.

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: It says SIGABRT in the AppDelegate, line: "return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));" I cannot find something more specific in the error log.

Comment: Where do you create textField? Do you create it in code, or is it an IBOutlet to a text field you created in IB? If I just alloc init a text field as the first line of your code, it no longer crashes (the constraints don't work properly, but at least it doesn't crash).

Answer (score -1):

**NSLayoutConstraint is only part of IOS 6. if you try to work this code other than IOS6 
( such as IOS 5, IOS 4.3) you are highly likely get this runtime error.**

Comment: My deployment target is 6.0